# Duplicate record with ef6 when child object saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a rather interesting problem and I am not quite sure how to properly get past it. In order to fully understand my problem, please keep in mind the following:

I am "Modulizing" my features. For example I have written a "Logger" dll that is then turned into a package. This DLL has its own DbContext and knows about certain tables as a result. Then I have written a "Tracker" dll which extends the Logger dll. The tracker dll is another module with its own Db Context and its own tables. It knows about the Logger dll only in the fact that it knows about its service layer and its model layer. Let me show you what that looks like:

Here are the Models (representing tables)

```
//Logger Module
public class LogError : ILogError
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //more stuff not relavent to the problem
}

//Tracker Module
public class ErrorTicket : IErrorTicket
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid LogErrorId { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TicketNumber { get; set; }
    //More properties not related to the problem

    public virtual LogError LogError { get; set; }
    public virtual ILogError MyLogError => LogError;
    public virtual ICollection<ErrorTicketNote> ErrorTicketNotes { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<IErrorTicketNote> MyErrorTicketNotes => ErrorTicketNotes;
}
```

Please keep in mind for the ErroTicket Class, I am using interfaces to expose certain methods. For example my interface only has getters and no setters, so when an interface is passed, the class cannot be updated. I would rather not go into a discussion as to why I do that as I am very certain it is not part of the problem. Just wanted to make a not so you understand why I have LogError and then MyLogError listed up there.

Now for my DbContext I have the following:

```
//Logger Module
public class LoggerDbContext : DbContext, ILoggerDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model.LogError> LogError { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model.LogInfo> LogInfo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ILogError> LogErrors => LogError;
    public IEnumerable<ILogInfo> LogInfos => LogInfo;

    public LoggerDbContext(string connectionString = "DefaultConnection") : base(connectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public void CreateLog(ILogError logError)
    {
        LogError.Add((Model.LogError) logError);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void CreateLog(ILogInfo logInfo)
    {
        LogInfo.Add((Model.LogInfo) logInfo);
        SaveChanges();
    }
}

//Tracker Module
public class TrackerDbContext : DbContext, ITrackerDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ErrorTicket> ErrorTicket { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ErrorTicketNote> ErrorTicketNote { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IErrorTicket> ErrorTickets => ErrorTicket;
    public IEnumerable<IErrorTicketNote> ErrorTicketNotes => ErrorTicketNote;

    public TrackerDbContext(string connectionString = "DefaultConnection") : base(connectionString) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public void CreateTicket(IErrorTicket errorTicket)
    {
        ErrorTicket.Add((ErrorTicket) errorTicket);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void ModifyTicket(IErrorTicket errorTicket)
    {
        Entry(errorTicket).State = EntityState.Modified;
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void CreateTicketNote(IErrorTicketNote errorTicketNote)
    {
        ErrorTicketNote.Add((ErrorTicketNote) errorTicketNote);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    public void ModifyTicketNote(IErrorTicketNote errorTicketNote)
    {
        Entry(errorTicketNote).State = EntityState.Modified;
        SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

As you can see two DbContext classes do not know about each other, but through my models I create a relation of foreign key. Now to my problem.

When an error occurs I have code that runs the following:

```
//the line bellow calls a Logger service that ends up invoking the method from the Logger DbContext - public void CreateLog(ILogError logError)

var var logError = _databaseLoggerService.Error(exception, message);

//Then I try to create my ErrorTicket and I assign the logError object to the class to create the relation of the foreign key.
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
var errorTicket = new ErrorTicket
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    LogErrorId = logError.Id,
    TimeCreated = currentTime,
    TimeResolved = null,
    TimeOfFirstOccurrence = currentTime,
    TimeOfLastOccurrence = currentTime,
    TotalOccurrences = 1,
    Resolved = false,
    Resolution = string.Empty,
    CommitNumber = string.Empty,
    TimeImplemented = null,
    LogError = (LogError) logError
};

_trackerDbContext.CreateTicket(errorTicket);
```

The problem that I get is the following:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.LogError'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LogError'. The duplicate key value is (769fb127-a8d8-40de-9492-fc61ca86cb16).
>   The statement has been terminated.

If I look at my LogError table, a record indeed exists with that key. I assume it was created when I called `_databaseLoggerService.Error(exception, message);`

What I do not understand, is why is this a problem for EF6 or how to get past it?

I have done a lot of research on the topic and I have found articles which state that because it is 2 sepparate DbContextes the second one may not know that the record exist so it when I caled .Add method, it marked ALL objects for insertoin and thus generated the INSERT queries. Which makes sense, and I could simply not call my db creation and let my tracker just create both objects for me. Which is all fine, however, the problem I have with that is when I try to modify 'the record, I get the exact same problem. Even though I marked the record as modify, it generates the insert queries.

My question is how do I get past this problem?

Comment: This sound like typical disconnected entity issue. Have you tried **not setting** the navigation property, just the FK (i.e. keep `LogErrorId = logError.Id`, remove `LogError = (LogError) logError`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I have and that works when inserting a new record. However, that doesn't resolve my issue of when I try to update the record.

Comment: You might consider posting repro for update scenario. To see for instance if the updating entity is already attached to the context, if the navigation property `LogError` is (lazy) populated etc. Setting `State = EntityState.Modified;` is too simplistic and works only for primitive properties, applying modications with navigation properties was never easy. You could try setting the `LogError = null` explicitly in that scenario, but it's hard to give you a general rule.

Comment: Looks like you only have to attach `logError` to the context as `Unchanged`. But to me the deeper problem is that your contexts have acquired service responsibilities. I.e. they violate the *single responsibility principle*. I would use one context for this part of your application and a service that uses an instance of this context whenever necessary. That will also enable you to commit everything in one transaction.

Comment: @GertArnold Could you please clarify couple of things. 1. You said I have to attach `logError` to the context as Unchanged, how do I do that? 2. You said they violate the single responsibility principle, is this because I am calling a logger service from within the Tracker service?